# Building with Vue Cli App and remote PHP api

Tags: php, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

I'm working on a project that uses Vue Cli and PHP

**my folder structure :**

[[image: folder structure]][]
-**admin** and **client** contain admin interface and user interface built with vue cli respectively.

*Admin* has access to modify content loaded into *client* template when logged in.

How do I connect the *admin* with the php *api* in development and production such that no route can be accessed in the admin page if the admin is not logged in.

such that if I visit  http://localhost:3001/admin/dashboard i will be redirected to http://localhost:3001/admin/ which is the login route.

my php runs on http://localhost:3000/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach :
Using Role and JWT you can restrict the routes .

Ref Here: https://medium.com/@ripoche.b/create-a-spa-with-role-based-authentication-with-laravel-and-vue-js-ac4b260b882f

Comment: I'm building with bare php -- no frameworks

Comment: using php https://www.sitepoint.com/php-authorization-jwt-json-web-tokens/

Comment: Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46899545/validate-user-in-php-api-via-js-frontend-framework-vuejs-concept High level approach is 1. Authentication of admin using a user name and password  - Againts a DB (Recommended) / Hardcoded value from config file . 2. Then in the api, you need to return a JWT Token (combination of role, user id ) 3. Store the token in client side using Local storage (Vue JS). 4. For each service call, example navigate to dbd, send this token and in API validate is it valid or not. Then show the page / show 401 accordingly.

Comment: So far, I have the option of using navigation guards on with vue and JWT token with php. I'm not really sure how to set this up especially  Vue-router navigation guard. Any refrence would help

Comment: In the beforeEnter action, you can check whether based on role matches / authorized. Ref : https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-implement-route-guard-in-vue-js-9929c93a13db